# Changing the overflow button color in Lollipop Appcompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme, android-styles

Hey I'm trying to change the color of overflow button without changing the text in the overflow menu.Here are my styles

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
... my base theme
<item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Overflow</item> // i tried adding android name space but it didn't work
<item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
... my overlow theme

<style name="Overflow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

The problem is the overflow button remains black. I could change the textPrimaryColor in my base theme but it would change the color of menu items as well.
Any idea what am I doing wrong? Cheers guys